# Simple Sql query conversion to Linq To Sql

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq-to-sql

I tried to convert this simple `sql` query to `linq to sql` query

```
SELECT * INTO temptable from EFESRDP0
ALTER TABLE temptable DROP COLUMN PASSWORD,SECONDPASS
SELECT * FROM temptable
DROP TABLE temptable
```

But I couldnt. Anyhelp would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Use Linqpad or Linqer tool to convert sql query to linq.

Comment: LinqPad converts SQL to Linq? I didn't know that. Could you tell how to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Linq to SQL has no equivalent for the table operations you're trying to perform, the short answer is you can't do that.

From the structure of the query though it looks like the following is happening:

1. All records from `EFESRDP0` are added to a previously non-existent table `temptable`
2. A few columns are dropped from `temptable`
3. The remaining data is returned as a recordset
4. The temporary table is dropped

Which is a long-winded way of specifying a list of columns to return from the original table, isn't it?  Bad SQL shouldn't be turned into even worse LINQ, it should be fixed.

In query syntax the simple form would be:

```
var results = 
    from row in context.EFESRDP0
    select new { row.ID, row.Name, row.LastLoginTime /* or whatever */ };
```

This will result in an SQL query similar to:

```
SELECT ID, Name, LastLoginTime
FROM EFESRDP0;
```

Which is a whole lot simpler than the SQL you posted and appears to do basically the same thing without all the table gymnastics.

Comment: Sorry but u get the wrong idea about the query, I'm getting rid of a certain column with that sql query, If there is another way of doing that tell me pls but as far as I know this is the only way to get rid of a column without actually deleting it from the database. Therefore your proposition is a bit different than what I look for

Comment: I think what Corey has said is exactly on the spot. Your SQL statements are doing exactly what he says. All you are doing is selecting all the columns except 2 from EFESRDP0. For example if originally your EFESRDP0 had columns like:
Field1, Field2, Password,SECONDPASS
Then your SQL statements are effectively doing this:
select field1, field2 from EFESRDP0

just like Corey has said.

Comment: There is a reason why I'm insisting on that query, there are 15 columns in total in table efesrdp , it is inconvenient to build a query like that. that is why I'm using this query. 
**Edit: However I get that there is no way to transform it. Therefore I accept this as an answer, Thank you all for your interest. **

Comment: @BarisY That is no excuse.  You are trying to dodge a very simple bit of work by doing something truly horrible with the SQL.  If you're really desperate to avoid typing the field names, make a view and use that.  Don't go making temporary tables and so on just to avoid typing field names, that's really poor practice.

Answer (score 0):

Since your SQL statements are effectively returning all columns except Password and SECONDPASS, you can do that with a simple Linq like Corey gave creating a new anonymous type. You can also have a type defined with all the columns except those 2 so you could get a typed result. ie: This sample returns only 3 columns from sample Northwind..Customers table:

```
void Main()
{
  DataContext db = new DataContext(@"server=.\SQLexpress;trusted_connection=yes;database=Northwind");
  Table<Customer> Customers = db.GetTable<Customer>();

  // for LinqPad
  //Customers.Dump();

}

[Table(Name = "Customers")]
public class Customer
{
    [Column]
    public string CustomerID { get; set; }
    [Column]
    public string ContactName { get; set; }
    [Column]
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
}
```